# is there a spinner for flash builder like this

Tags: flash, apache-flex, list, spinner, builder

Is there a spark component that acts like this?

I've tried a spinner list and a combo box they both didn't look good in the app.

Please post sample code.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using a normal List? Compared with your screen there's only two issues I see with using a normal list. 

The first being the lack of those radio button icons which could be solved by using a custom itemrenderer. The second being that you want the list to appear rather than just shown on screen. This could be accomplished with a popup: http://devgirl.org/2011/06/07/flex-4-5-mobile-development-alert-popup-and-other-skinnable-popups-with-source-code/ This is probably pretty close to what the flextras guys do though I have to say I'm not a fan of how their list looks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Flextras Mobile DropDownList](https://www.flextras.com/index.cfm?event=ProductHome&productID=21), with our RadioButtonRenderer and our PopUpSkin 2.

You can play with it [here](https://www.flextras.com/MobileComponents/Samples/MobileDropDownList/).  Here is some code you could use to test your own sample; once you have our mobile component SWC in your library path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" xmlns:flextras="http://www.flextras.com/mxml" >
<mx:Script>
 <![CDATA[
  import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
  [Bindable] public var dataProvider : ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
   {label:"United States of America")},
   {label:"Alabama")},
   {label:"Alaska")},
   {label:"Arizona")},
  ]);
 ]]>
</mx:Script>

<flextras:DropDownList id="mobileComp" 
 dataProvider="{this.dataProvider}" 
 width="100%" 
 skinClass="com.flextras.mobile.dropDownList.skins.DropDownListMobileSkin_PopUp_2"
 itemRenderer="com.flextras.mobile.shared.renderers.RadioButtonRenderer"
>
</flextras:DropDownList>
</s:Application>
```

It will give you a close approximation of what is in the screenshots.

Comment: i get an error  "Could not resolve <flextras:DropDownList> to a component implementation."

Comment: Did you register on our site, download our mobile component SWC, and add it to your library path?